# React peer dependency resolution

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, material-ui

I'm confused by the following error message that occurs while trying to install Material UI into a React app.  I'm running React v18.2.0 and typescript v5.2.2.

Install command [referenced here](https://mui.com/material-ui/getting-started/installation/):

```
npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled
```

Output:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: react-scripts@5.0.1
npm ERR! Found: typescript@5.2.2
npm ERR! node_modules/typescript
npm ERR!   peer typescript@">= 2.7" from fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin@6.5.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin
npm ERR!     fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin@"^6.5.0" from react-dev-utils@12.0.1
npm ERR!     node_modules/react-dev-utils
npm ERR!       react-dev-utils@"^12.0.1" from react-scripts@5.0.1
npm ERR!       node_modules/react-scripts
npm ERR!         react-scripts@"5.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer typescript@">=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta" from tsutils@3.21.0npm ERR!   node_modules/tsutils
npm ERR!     tsutils@"^3.21.0" from @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@5.48.2
npm ERR!     node_modules/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin
npm ERR!       @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@"^5.5.0" from eslint-config-react-app@7.0.1
npm ERR!       node_modules/eslint-config-react-app
npm ERR!         eslint-config-react-app@"^7.0.1" from react-scripts@5.0.1
npm ERR!         node_modules/react-scripts
npm ERR!         1 more (the root project)
npm ERR!       1 more (eslint-plugin-jest)
npm ERR!     tsutils@"^3.21.0" from @typescript-eslint/type-utils@5.48.2
npm ERR!     node_modules/@typescript-eslint/type-utils
npm ERR!       @typescript-eslint/type-utils@"5.48.2" from @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@5.48.2
npm ERR!       node_modules/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin
npm ERR!         @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@"^5.5.0" from eslint-config-react-app@7.0.1
npm ERR!         node_modules/eslint-config-react-app
npm ERR!         1 more (eslint-plugin-jest)
npm ERR!     1 more (@typescript-eslint/typescript-estree)
npm ERR!   1 more (the root project)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peerOptional typescript@"^3.2.1 || ^4" from react-scripts@5.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react-scripts
npm ERR!   react-scripts@"5.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: typescript@4.9.5
npm ERR! node_modules/typescript
npm ERR!   peerOptional typescript@"^3.2.1 || ^4" from react-scripts@5.0.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-scripts
npm ERR!     react-scripts@"5.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

There seem to be multiple separate issues reported above and I'm inexperienced reading this exact error message, but starting with the first one, it seems to be saying the peer dependency is typescript >=2.7.  I am interpreting it correctly?

My dependencies from package.json

```
 "dependencies": {
        "@arcgis/core": "^4.26.5",
        "@azure/msal-browser": "^2.32.2",
        "@azure/msal-react": "^1.5.2",
        "@esri/calcite-components-react": "^1.0.5",
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
        "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
        "@types/jest": "^29.5.8",
        "@types/node": "^20.9.2",
        "@types/react": "^18.2.37",
        "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.15",
        "bootstrap-icons": "^1.10.3",
        "http-proxy-middleware": "^2.0.6",
        "react": "^18.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
        "react-router-dom": "^6.8.2",
        "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
        "recharts": "^2.5.0",
        "typescript": "^5.2.2",
        "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
      },
"devDependencies": {
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^7.0.1",
    "jest-editor-support": "^31.0.1"
  }
```

Since I'm running typescript 5.2.2, which is greater than or equal to 2.7, I don't understand why the dependency isn't met.  What am I missing?

**Update & Solution:**
Thanks to Admin's advice below, here are the steps that solved my problem:

Step 1: Downgrade typescript by editing package.json and setting typescript to v4

Step 2: Delete package-lock.json and the node_modules folder

Step 3: run command: npm install

At this point, we're actually using typescript v4

Step 4: run command: npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled

Comment: Can't say much without seeing devDependencies.

Comment: I've updated the original code snipper to include devDependencies.